# Parse simple JSON Array without key

Tags: android, json, android-json

I need help with parsing simple JSONArray like this:

```
{
 "text":[
  "Morate popuniti polje tekst."
 ]
}
```

I have tried with this but I failed:

```
 if (response_str != null) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response_str);
        JSONArray arrayJson = jsonObj.getJSONArray("text");

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = arrayJson.optJSONObject(i);
            error = obj.getString("text");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a `JSONArray` text. There is no array of `JSONObject`.

```
{  // Json object node 
"text":[ // json array text 
 "Morate popuniti polje tekst." // value
]
}
```

Just use

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayJson.length(); i++) {
  String value =  arrayJson.get(i);
}
```

In fact there is no need for a loop as you have only 1 element in json array

You can just use

```
String value = (String) arrayJson.get(0); // index 0 . need to cast it to string
```

Or

```
String value = arrayJson.getString(0); // index 0
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

```
public Object get (int index)

Added in API level 1
Returns the value at index.

Throws
JSONException   if this array has no value at index, or if that value is the null reference. This method returns normally if the value is JSONObject#NULL.
public boolean getBoolean (int index)
```

`getString`

```
public String getString (int index)

Added in API level 1
Returns the value at index if it exists, coercing it if necessary.

Throws
JSONException   if no such value exists.
```

Comment: Anyway, dcharms answer is more clear, so you should edit your, because somebody else could have same problem.

Answer (score 9):

Your `JSONArray` is an array of Strings. You can iterate this way

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response_str);
JSONArray arrayJson = jsonObj.getJSONArray("text");

for (int i = 0; i < arrayJson.length(); i++) {
    String error = arrayJson.getString(i);
    // Do something with each error here
}
```

Comment: This works, but Raghunandan answered first, so I will acpet his answer, sorry. Anyway, thank you, this is more complete and clear solution.

Comment: You are free to pick whichever answer you like, but if it is a more complete and clear solution, maybe it should be chosen?

Comment: He answered faster than you, so I test it and it works, that's fair.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response_str);
JSONArray arrayJson = jsonObject.getJSONArray("text");
String theString = arrayJson.getString(0);
```